# How can a macro provide values for tokens passed to it, and expand and paste these together?

Tags: c++, c, macros, preprocessor

My current solution:

```
#define TEMPLATE_X_YX_(X, Y, a, b, c) a ## X ## b ## Y ## X ## c
// other templates may also exist, with different parameter arrangements

#define GENERATOR(name, template, ...) \
        const auto name##1 = &TEMPLATE##template(A, 1, __VA_ARGS__); \
        const auto name##2 = &TEMPLATE##template(B, 2, __VA_ARGS__); \
        const auto name##3 = &TEMPLATE##template(C, 3, __VA_ARGS__);

GENERATOR(example, _X_YX_, example_, _mid_, _suffix)

// expected output:

        const auto example1 = &example_A_mid_1A_suffix;
        const auto example2 = &example_B_mid_2B_suffix;
        const auto example3 = &example_C_mid_3C_suffix;
```

But what I find frustrating is the need to define and reference the `TEMPLATE` macro, and for it to be out-of-line with the actual template definition I'm using.  What I would *like* might be more like:

```
GENERATOR(example, example_, X, _mid_, Y, X, _suffix)
```

I tried a few experiments with nesting and trying to force the expansion of X and Y as parameters of deeper macros, but the preprocessor was having none of it.

An application for this is to quickly fold large lists of per-type C functions with complex names into C++ overloaded simple names.

I'm kind of wondering if I can do something with some pre-defined macros for the substitution parameters (which might include commas in their definitions), to force an extra round of macro expansion before descending, but I can't figure out a clear plan for that right now.  And even if it worked it might be illegal.

Comment: I don't totally follow the question, but I think you're struggling with the fact that the operands of a `##` preprocessor operator (or a `#` preprocessor operator) are not themselves macro-expanded.  The usual solution is to interpose an intermediate macro, as you indeed seem to have done.  That's how it needs to be done.

Comment: Question is why would you want to do this?  I don't know about other IDEs but whenever I've done something similar, Intellisense in Visual Studio doesn't know about such names.  Also, you can't find where something has been modified.

Comment: @cup Because you can't template anything when the name of the methods you need to call keep changing based on types.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but writing macro loops that use external state inside of the loop body (the state being the values of `X` and `Y` in your case) is tricky, so I'm going to use a small library for that: [`macro_sequence_for`](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/macro_sequence_for) (which I'm the author of).

I've also changed the pattern syntax a bit, because it's easier to loop over sequences of the form `(a)(b)(b)` (as opposed to `a, b, c`). Looping over comma-separated lists requires boilerplate macros, the amount of which limits the max number of sequence elements.

<kbd>[run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:36,endLineNumber:18,positionColumn:36,positionLineNumber:18,selectionStartColumn:36,selectionStartLineNumber:18,startColumn:36,startLineNumber:18),source:%27%23include+%3Chttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/HolyBlackCat/macro_sequence_for/master/include/macro_sequence_for.h%3E%0A%0A%23define+GENERATOR(name,+seq)+%5C%0A++++const+auto+SF_CAT(name,1)+%3D+%26DETAIL_MAKE_INIT(A,+1,+seq)%3B%5C%0A++++const+auto+SF_CAT(name,2)+%3D+%26DETAIL_MAKE_INIT(B,+2,+seq)%3B%5C%0A++++const+auto+SF_CAT(name,3)+%3D+%26DETAIL_MAKE_INIT(C,+3,+seq)%3B%0A%0A//+Generates+a+single+initializer.%0A%23define+DETAIL_MAKE_INIT(x,+y,+seq)+%5C%0A++++SF_FOR_EACH(SF_NULL,+DETAIL_CAT_STEP,+SF_STATE,,+SF_FOR_EACH(DETAIL_BODY,+SF_STATE,+SF_NULL,+(x,+y),+seq))%0A%0A//+Loop+body+for+the+inner+loop.%0A//+Turns+the+initial+sequence+into+a+sequence+of+parts+to+be+concatenated.%0A%23define+DETAIL_BODY(n,+d,+e)+DETAIL_ELEM(e,+SF_CAT(DETAIL_PLACEHOLDER_,+e)+d)%0A%0A//+Placeholders.%0A%23define+DETAIL_PLACEHOLDER_X(x,+y)+,x%0A%23define+DETAIL_PLACEHOLDER_Y(x,+y)+,y%0A%0A//+Extra+indirection+to+turn+%60,%60+into+argument+separator.%0A%23define+DETAIL_ELEM(...)+DETAIL_ELEM_A(__VA_ARGS__)%0A//+If+given+%60var_name,+,+value%60,+returns+%60(value)%60.%0A//+Otherwise+if+given+%60text,+...%60,+returns+%60(text)%60.%0A%23define+DETAIL_ELEM_A(e,+f,+...)+DETAIL_ELEM_B%23%23__VA_OPT__(_VAR)(e,+__VA_ARGS__)%0A%23define+DETAIL_ELEM_B(e,+...)+(e)%0A%23define+DETAIL_ELEM_B_VAR(e,+...)+(__VA_ARGS__)%0A%0A//+A+step+function+for+the+outer+loop.+Concatenates+(appends)+the+element+to+the+state.%0A%23define+DETAIL_CAT_STEP(n,+d,+e)+SF_CAT(d,+e)%0A%0AGENERATOR(foo,+(x_is_)(X)(_and_y_is_)(Y))%0A//+Expands+to:%0A//+const+auto+foo1+%3D+%26x_is_A_and_y_is_1%3B%0A//+const+auto+foo2+%3D+%26x_is_B_and_y_is_2%3B%0A//+const+auto+foo3+%3D+%26x_is_C_and_y_is_3%3B%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.22570909891783,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1600,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors+-E+-o+-%27,overrides:!(),paneName:GCC,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:GCC,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:46.40234948604993,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:13,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,paneName:%27GCC+output%27,wrap:%270%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27GCC+output%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:53.59765051395007,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50.77429090108217,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)</kbd>

```
GENERATOR(foo, (x_is_)(X)(_and_y_is_)(Y))
// Expands to:
// const auto foo1 = &x_is_A_and_y_is_1;
// const auto foo2 = &x_is_B_and_y_is_2;
// const auto foo3 = &x_is_C_and_y_is_3;
```

And the macro implementation:

```
#include <macro_sequence_for.h>

#define GENERATOR(name, seq) \
    const auto SF_CAT(name,1) = &DETAIL_MAKE_INIT(A, 1, seq);\
    const auto SF_CAT(name,2) = &DETAIL_MAKE_INIT(B, 2, seq);\
    const auto SF_CAT(name,3) = &DETAIL_MAKE_INIT(C, 3, seq);

// Generates a single initializer.
#define DETAIL_MAKE_INIT(x, y, seq) \
    SF_FOR_EACH(SF_NULL, DETAIL_CAT_STEP, SF_STATE,, SF_FOR_EACH(DETAIL_BODY, SF_STATE, SF_NULL, (x, y), seq))

// Loop body for the inner loop.
// Turns the initial sequence into a sequence of parts to be concatenated.
#define DETAIL_BODY(n, d, e) DETAIL_ELEM(e, SF_CAT(DETAIL_PLACEHOLDER_, e) d)

// Placeholders.
#define DETAIL_PLACEHOLDER_X(x, y) ,x
#define DETAIL_PLACEHOLDER_Y(x, y) ,y

// Extra indirection to turn `,` into argument separator.
#define DETAIL_ELEM(...) DETAIL_ELEM_A(__VA_ARGS__)
// If given `var_name, , value`, returns `(value)`.
// Otherwise if given `text, ...`, returns `(text)`.
#define DETAIL_ELEM_A(e, f, ...) DETAIL_ELEM_B##__VA_OPT__(_VAR)(e, __VA_ARGS__)
#define DETAIL_ELEM_B(e, ...) (e)
#define DETAIL_ELEM_B_VAR(e, ...) (__VA_ARGS__)

// A step function for the outer loop. Concatenates (appends) the element to the state.
#define DETAIL_CAT_STEP(n, d, e) SF_CAT(d, e)
```

There are two loops here, and the output of the first one is fed as an input sequence to the second one.

The first loop expands the variables in the input, so `(x_is_)(X)(_and_y_is_)(Y)` turns into `(x_is_)(A)(_and_y_is_)(B)`, and the second loop then concatenates the elements into a single identifier.

---

And the same thing backported to C++17 (no `__VA_OPT__` and no omitting `,` before the empty variadic argument):

```
#include <macro_sequence_for.h>

#define GENERATOR(name, seq) \
    const auto SF_CAT(name,1) = &DETAIL_MAKE_INIT(A, 1, seq);\
    const auto SF_CAT(name,2) = &DETAIL_MAKE_INIT(B, 2, seq);\
    const auto SF_CAT(name,3) = &DETAIL_MAKE_INIT(C, 3, seq);

// Generates a single initializer.
#define DETAIL_MAKE_INIT(x, y, seq) \
    SF_FOR_EACH(SF_NULL, DETAIL_CAT_STEP, SF_STATE,, SF_FOR_EACH(DETAIL_BODY, SF_STATE, SF_NULL, (x, y), seq))

// Loop body for the inner loop.
// Turns the initial sequence into a sequence of parts to be concatenated.
#define DETAIL_BODY(n, d, e) DETAIL_ELEM(e, SF_CAT(DETAIL_PLACEHOLDER_, e) d, _VAR,,)

// Placeholders.
#define DETAIL_PLACEHOLDER_X(x, y) ,x
#define DETAIL_PLACEHOLDER_Y(x, y) ,y

// Extra indirection to turn `,` into argument separator.
#define DETAIL_ELEM(...) DETAIL_ELEM_A(__VA_ARGS__)
// If given `var_name,    , value, _VAR, ,`, returns `(value)`.
// If given `text    , ..., _VAR ,     ,  `, returns `(text)`.
#define DETAIL_ELEM_A(e, f, value, marker, ...) SF_CAT(DETAIL_ELEM_B, marker)(e, value)
#define DETAIL_ELEM_B(e, unused) (e)
#define DETAIL_ELEM_B_VAR(unused, value) (value)

// A step function for the outer loop. Concatenates (appends) the element to the state.
#define DETAIL_CAT_STEP(n, d, e) SF_CAT(d, e)
```

---

If you prefer the call syntax without parentheses (`x_is_ ARG_X _and_y_is_ ARG_Y` as opposed to `(x_is_)(X)(_and_y_is_)(Y)`), you can achieve it by defining `ARG_X` to `)(X)(` (same for `ARG_Y`), and wrapping the macro argument in `(` `)` before passing it to the `SF_SEQ_FOR`.

Comment: I like your syntax better than mine, but `__VA_OPT__` is just a bit too modern for what I can depend on.

Comment: @sh1 I'll see if I can rewrite it without `__VA_OPT__`.

Comment: @sh1 See edit. *"I like your syntax better"* Hah, yours looked better to me. I've also added a note how to support your syntax with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, up to a modest limit:

```
#define JOIN_(x, y) x ## y
#define JOIN(x, y) JOIN_(x, y)
#define PREFIX_X(X, Y, end) JOIN(X, end)
#define PREFIX_Y(X, Y, end) JOIN(Y, end)
#define PREFIX(X, Y, end) end

#define UNPACK0(X, Y, t, ...) t
#define UNPACK1(X, Y, t, p, ...) JOIN(t, PREFIX##p(X, Y, UNPACK0(X, Y, __VA_ARGS__)))
#define UNPACK2(X, Y, t, p, ...) JOIN(t, PREFIX##p(X, Y, UNPACK1(X, Y, __VA_ARGS__)))
// ... lots more of the same ...
#define UNPACK9(X, Y, t, p, ...) JOIN(t, PREFIX##p(X, Y, UNPACK8(X, Y, __VA_ARGS__)))

#define UNPACK(X, Y, ...) UNPACK9(X, Y, __VA_ARGS__,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,)
#define ARG_X ,_X,
#define ARG_Y ,_Y,

#define GENERATOR(name, ...) \
        const auto name##1 = &UNPACK(A, 1, __VA_ARGS__); \
        const auto name##2 = &UNPACK(B, 2, __VA_ARGS__); \
        const auto name##3 = &UNPACK(C, 3, __VA_ARGS__);

GENERATOR(example,  prefix_ ARG_X _mid_ ARG_Y ARG_X _suffix)
```